# Concurrent login

Tags: security, coldfusion

Anyone here tried to implement a way in ColdFusion to not let same login account to be used concurrently, so if one login and the other login will either be disabled or kick out the first one.

please share your experience.

Comment: Step 1 - store the information when someone logs in.  Step 2 - check to see if the person is already logged in.  Step 3 - store the information when the person stops being logged in for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two methods, the first is significantly lighter on performance than the other.

### Deny any user who tries to login after the first.

- Add a loggedin field to your users table. Simple 0/1.
- When the user logs in, run a query like this

LoginQuery:

```
<cfquery name="validate">
  select userID,loggedIn,data,you,want
    from users
   where username=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.username#">
     <!--- I hope you're hashing/encrypting passwords, but this is a simple demo --->
     and password=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.password#">
</cfquery>

<cfif validate.recordcount eq 1>
  <cfif validate.loggedIn eq 0>
    <cfset session.userID = validate.userID
    ...collect whatever info from table
    <cfquery name="validate">
      update users
       set loggedIn=1
     where userID=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#validate.userID#">
    </cfquery>
  <cfelse>
    Someone else is logged in.
  </cfif>
<cfelse>
  Invalid credentials.
</cfif>
```

When the user logs out, set the loggedIn flag in the table to 0

```
<cfquery name="validate">
  update users
   set loggedIn=0
 where userID=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.userID#">
</cfquery>
```

Now, because a lot of users navigate away from the site, or walk away from the computer, you can use **Application.cfc**'s onSessionEnd method, which executes when a session ends to do the same query as logout with one change. `Session` scope is not available to the method, instead you need to use `Sessionscope` argument of the method.

Therein lies the one flaw with this method. If a user walks away from the machine/navigates away from the page, noone can login til the first user's session expires. So if your session timeout is set to 20 minutes, and you walk away from the machine, noone can login to that account for 20 minutes. It's for this reason that you'd really want a short-ish session timeout (but nothing obnoxiously short that would penalize a user for taking too long to complete a form).

```
<cffunction name="onSessionEnd">
    <cfargument name = "SessionScope" required=true/>
    <cfargument name = "AppScope" required=true/>
    <cfquery name="validate">
      update users
        set loggedIn=0
      where userID=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#SessionScope.userID#">
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

### Kick the first out after a second logs in

The problem with this route is that it really needs to run a query on every page (or at least, every member-specific page. You could conceivably have 10 users on the front page of the site under the same username, but who cares. But any, aside from the most recently logged in, who try to access a member page, are immediately kicked out. Of course, they would attempt to log back in, now becoming the most-recent, and kicking *anyone else* out. That's another downside to this practice.

Add a loginkey field to your users table.

When the user logs in, populate this field with a value unique to the user, you can do something like.

```
#randrange(1,10000000)#
```

Store this key in users.loginkey and session.loginkey.

Match this on each page, or at least each members page. If the first-login is browsing the front pages, let it slide, save on performance.

```
<cfquery name="validate">
  select userID
    from users
   where loginkey=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.loginkey#">
     <!--- since you're doing this, might as well validate credentials --->
     and password=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#session.password#">
     and username=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#session.username#">
</cfquery>
```

You can move that loginkey section of the `where` statement to an if statement (like I demonstrated in the first method) and explain to the user why they were kicked out. Or you can do this query side.

(You can also use session.cfid and cftoken as the unique identifier, which is very valid, I simply wanted to show you where and how you'd need to store the data if you were creating a separate key. I personally would use cfid/cftoken because... why add more performance overhead)

Comment: @QaisMaash As long as everything is accessing the same database, there's no reason either shouldn't work. The second method has the infinitesimally small chance that two users would get the same key, but with a complex enough string, that's not worth mentioning. However a key like #randrange(1,10)# has high chance of problems.